# How to bin values in the mapper?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, aggregation, binning

I'm new to Hadoop MapReduce and I've recently encountered a problem in how to do the binning of output values in the mapper. My mapper creates a Text, IntWritable output with a dataset ID as a key and a length of metadata description as a value. My goal is to bin the frequencies of metadata length into 3 groups: 1-200 characters, 201-400 characters, and 401+ characters. The output file looks as follows (first column is the key, second column is the value - length of metadata):

```
1   256
2   344
3   234
4   160
5   432
6   121
7   551
8   239
9   283
10   80
...
```

Based on the values above the binning result should display:

```
1-200     3
201-400   5
401-...   2
```

Any ideas on how to approach it? Should I do it as the Mapper cleanup, Combiner or within a Reducer? Code examples or references to other online sources would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is known that data needs to binned into the three bins. These bin can be declared statically in the `Mapper` like:

```
Text BIN1 = new Text("1-200");     // bin-1
Text BIN2 = new Text("200-400");   // bin-2
Text BIN3 = new Text("400-...");   // bin-3
```

Now create a `HashMap<Text, Integer> map` in the map. As the Mapper reads the data, it will update the count for the respective `bin` in the `map`. Then write this `map` in the `cleanup()` method. The output of the Mapper is `Text` and `IntWritable` (which is count for each bin from the `map`).

If there are multiple Mappers in the job, then `Mapper` output can be aggregated in the `Reducer`, with simple sum of the `Iterable<IntWritable>` values for each key (`Text`).